# How to enable MULTIPLE buttons after checking ONE checkbox in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to enable 3 buttons, after checking the LAST check box on my page using JS. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload=function() {
  df=document.forms[0];
  df[1].disabled=true;
  df[0].onclick=function(){
  df[1].disabled=(df[1].disabled)?false:true;
  }
  df=document.forms[0];
  df[2].disabled=true;
  df[1].onclick=function(){
  df[2].disabled=(df[2].disabled)?false:true;
  }
   df=document.forms[0];
  df[3].disabled=true;
  df[2].onclick=function(){
  df[3].disabled=(df[3].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[4].disabled=true;
  df[3].onclick=function(){
  df[4].disabled=(df[4].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[5].disabled=true;
  df[4].onclick=function(){
  df[5].disabled=(df[5].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[6].disabled=true;
  df[5].onclick=function(){
  df[6].disabled=(df[6].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[7].disabled=true;
  df[6].onclick=function(){
  df[7].disabled=(df[7].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[8].disabled=true;
  df[7].onclick=function(){
  df[8].disabled=(df[8].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[10].disabled=true;
  df[8].onclick=function(){
  df[10].disabled=(df[10].disabled)?false:true;
  }
 }
//-->
```

I need to add two more buttons to this script. When I script it this way, it only works with the last button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload=function() {
  df=document.forms[0];
  df[1].disabled=true;
  df[0].onclick=function(){
  df[1].disabled=(df[1].disabled)?false:true;
  }
  df=document.forms[0];
  df[2].disabled=true;
  df[1].onclick=function(){
  df[2].disabled=(df[2].disabled)?false:true;
  }
   df=document.forms[0];
  df[3].disabled=true;
  df[2].onclick=function(){
  df[3].disabled=(df[3].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[4].disabled=true;
  df[3].onclick=function(){
  df[4].disabled=(df[4].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[5].disabled=true;
  df[4].onclick=function(){
  df[5].disabled=(df[5].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[6].disabled=true;
  df[5].onclick=function(){
  df[6].disabled=(df[6].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[7].disabled=true;
  df[6].onclick=function(){
  df[7].disabled=(df[7].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[8].disabled=true;
  df[7].onclick=function(){
  df[8].disabled=(df[8].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[10].disabled=true;
  df[8].onclick=function(){
  df[10].disabled=(df[10].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[11].disabled=true;
  df[8].onclick=function(){
  df[11].disabled=(df[11].disabled)?false:true;
  }
    df=document.forms[0];
  df[12].disabled=true;
  df[8].onclick=function(){
  df[12].disabled=(df[12].disabled)?false:true;
  }
 }
//-->
</script>
```

DF's 12,11,10 & 9 are buttons. I need button 1 or DF 9 enabled always. I need buttons 2,3 & 4 or DF's 10,11 & 12 to "enable" when my last check box is checked. This checkbox is DF 8. Please help!

Comment: Apologies if I'm mis-reading your code, but why are you not using some kind of loop, instead of writing out each and every element... and repeatedly assigning the form to `df`? Also, there is no need to put your script in HTML comments. It hasn't been necessary since something like Netscape 2.

Comment: You don't need to keep re-assigning the same object to `df`. I.e., don't keep coding `df=document.forms[0];`. Once is enough; it will retain its value.

Comment: Note: you haven't needed to hide your javascript blocking using !-- since 1997

Comment: It has been awhile since I've done this. Been on the management side of things for YEARS now. But that does make sense, I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: It probably wasnt to long after 1997 when I did this for a living.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not self-documenting. It's therefore very hard to maintain it and to get it understood by other developers. I strongly recommend you to work on that as well. Start using sensible variable names and so on.

But I think I see the problem. You're **overriding** the onclick handler of `df[8]` everytime by reassigning it instead of attaching a new function to the existing handler. This way only the *last* assigned onclick function will really execute.

So, instead of

```
df=document.forms[0];
df[10].disabled=true;
df[8].onclick=function(){
    df[10].disabled=(df[10].disabled)?false:true;
}
df=document.forms[0];
df[11].disabled=true;
df[8].onclick=function(){
    df[11].disabled=(df[11].disabled)?false:true;
}
df=document.forms[0];
df[12].disabled=true;
df[8].onclick=function(){
    df[12].disabled=(df[12].disabled)?false:true;
}
```

you need to do

```
df = document.forms[0];

df[10].disabled = true;
df[11].disabled = true;
df[12].disabled = true;

df[8].onclick = function() {
    df[10].disabled = !df[10].disabled;
    df[11].disabled = !df[11].disabled;
    df[12].disabled = !df[12].disabled;
}
```

*(note that I also simplified the way how you're toggling the disabled attribute)*

Again, your code is not self-documenting. This may or may not solve your real problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I REALLY appricate it. And that visual helps me understand how to simply the code.

Answer (score 0):

DRY.  It's a programming paradigm, "don't repeat yourself".  Your code is a perfect candidate for using loops to handle the logic.  Also as mentioned by others, self-documenting code is very useful, both for you and for future developers working on your code.

Here's one example

```
var controlls   = 12,
    alwaysOn    = new Array(controlls),
    form        = document.forms[0];

// These never get disabled
alwaysOn[0] = true;
alwaysOn[9] = true;

// Handle the general case
for(var i=0; i<controlls; i++){
    // Disable unless never disabled
    form[i].disabled = !alwaysOn[i];

    // This input disables it's younger sibling, unless that sibling is never disabled
    if(!alwaysOn[i+1]){
        form[i].onclick = function(){
            form[i+1].disabled = !form[i+1].disabled;
        }
    }
}

// Handle the special case, explicitly
form[8].onclick = function(){
    form[10].disabled = !form[10].disabled;
    form[11].disabled = !form[11].disabled;
    form[12].disabled = !form[12].disabled;
}
```

I didn't test this code but I did run it through JSLint. Not claiming this to be the end-all solution to your issue, just wanted to provide an example (however silly) of what people mean by "self-documenting code".  I could have gone further with it but hopefully you get the idea.

Good luck.